# StackSize exceeded - trying to make an API

Tags: node.js, typescript, api-design, es6-proxy

I'm trying to create a dynamic API using TypeScript and ES6 Proxies on top of NodeJs. I implemented the API but after a little bit of testing i found that i exceed the stack size. Even if i try with the --stack-size set to 16000 but it still exceeds it! I think i have some recursive method that i'm not seeing.

Here's my code:

```
export class StackPlate {
public static build(name: string, parent: StackPlate, callback: (type: string, data: any) => any) {
    return (new StackPlate(name, parent, callback)).proxy;
}

private callback: (type: string, data: any) => any;
private parent: StackPlate;
private childs: {[key: string]:  StackPlate} = {};
private name: string = "";
public proxy;

constructor(name: string, parent: StackPlate, callback: (type: string, data: any) => any) {
    this.parent = parent;
    this.name = name;
    this.callback = callback;

    this.proxy = new Proxy((...parameters) => {
        let stack = [this.name];
        let parent = this.parent;
        while(parent) {
            stack.push(parent.getName());
            parent = parent.getParent();
        }
        stack = stack.reverse();
        return this.callback("call", {stack, parameters});
    }, {
        get: (target, property: string): any => {
            if(this.childs[property])
                return this.childs[property].proxy;

            let child = StackPlate.build(property, this, this.callback);
            this.childs[property] = child;

            this.callback("get", {target, property, child});

            return child.proxy;
        },
        set: (target, property: string, value: any, receiver): boolean => {
            let stack = [property, this.name];
            let parent = this.parent;
            while(parent) {
                stack.push(parent.getName());
                parent = parent.getParent();
            }
            stack = stack.reverse();
            return this.callback("set", {stack, property, target, value});
        }
    });
}

public getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public getChilds() {
    return this.childs;
}

public getParent() {
    return this.parent;
}
}
```

I'm using TypeScript 2.4.2 and Node 8.7.0 (also tried on a lower 8.x version). In my config i have set the target to es6. I can't understand were my problem is!

PS: Test:

```
let plate = StackPlate.build("test", undefined, console.log);
plate.a.b.c();
```

Comment: I recommend putting some logging in your loops:  `while (parent) { console.log(parent.getName()); //...` to see if you are getting stuck in the loop for some reason (i.e. a traversal problem etc).

Comment: hi! thanks for your help! i actually just fount he issue. inside the get trap i used the `StackPlate.build` method that actually returns the proxy, not the object itself! and that created a loop :)

Comment: Since you've solved your own question, you can either write your own answer (if you think this would be useful to others as a reference) or you delete your question since it is done now.  Please do one or the other to wrap up the question.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue! Inside the get trap i used the `StackPlate.build` method that actually returns the proxy, not the object itself! And that created a loop :)